# Specific query in java spring called from rest controller

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to filter a table called Measure through its field customerId. This is what the beginning of the controller for the path looks like:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/nodes/{id}/ports/{portid}/measures")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getPortMeasures(@PathVariable long id, @PathVariable long portid,
                                         @RequestParam Optional<Long> from,
                                         @RequestParam Optional<String> order,
                                         @RequestParam Optional<String> countername,
                                         @RequestParam Optional<Long> to) {
```

Followed by the method that calls the query undernath

```
if (order.isPresent() && order.get().equals("asc")) {
            return ResponseRestBuilder.createSuccessResponse(
                    measureRepository.
                            searchAsc
                                    (networkElementList.get(0).ip, portList.get(0).rack, portList.get(0).frame, portList.get(0).slot,
                                            portList.get(0).portSerial, countername.get(), from.orElse(0L), to.orElse(99999999999999999L)));
        }
        else{
            return ResponseRestBuilder.createSuccessResponse(
                    measureRepository.
                            searchDesc
                                    (networkElementList.get(0).ip, portList.get(0).rack, portList.get(0).frame, portList.get(0).slot,
                                            portList.get(0).portSerial, countername.get(), from.orElse(0L), to.orElse(99999999999999999L)));
        }
```

This is what the queries look like:

```
    @Query("SELECT mes FROM Measure mes WHERE " +
        "mes.nodeIp = (:nodeIp) AND " +
        "mes.rack = (:rack) AND " +
        "mes.frame = (:frame) AND " +
        "mes.slot = (:slot) AND " +
        "mes.portSerial = (:portSerial) AND " +
        "lower(mes.counterName) LIKE concat('%', lower(:countername), '%')  AND"+
        "mes.timestamp > (:timestamp1) AND " +
        "mes.timestamp < (:timestamp2) "+
        "ORDER BY mes.timestamp DESC")


List<Measure> searchDesc(@Param("nodeIp") String nodeIp, @Param("rack") String rack, @Param("frame") String frame,
                            @Param("slot") String slot, @Param("portSerial") String portSerial, @Param("countername") String countername,
                         @Param("timestamp1") Long timestamp1, @Param("timestamp2") Long timestamp2);



@Query("SELECT mes FROM Measure mes WHERE " +
        "mes.nodeIp = :nodeIp AND " +
        "mes.rack = :rack AND " +
        "mes.frame = :frame AND " +
        "mes.slot = :slot AND " +
        "mes.portSerial = :portSerial AND " +
        "lower(mes.counterName) LIKE concat('%', lower(:countername), '%') AND " +
        "mes.timestamp > :timestamp1 AND " +
        "mes.timestamp < :timestamp2 "+
        "ORDER BY mes.timestamp ASC")


List<Measure> searchAsc(@Param("nodeIp") String nodeIp, @Param("rack") String rack, @Param("frame") String frame,
                         @Param("slot") String slot, @Param("portSerial") String portSerial, @Param("countername") String countername,
                         @Param("timestamp1") Long timestamp1, @Param("timestamp2") Long timestamp2);
```

It's not filtering anything because the controller replies with 0 rows. I'm 100% confident there are actual rows because I've checked with other rest calls. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: debug
[image: debug screenshot]

Comment: maybe try logging the querries or a debugger to make sure everything is as you expect it to be

Comment: Tried already, it is as I am excepting, the query just isn't working

Comment: have you tried running the generated query with the values?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is with the timestamp field ,it seems from the code that you are passing a long, but actually it's waiting for a timestamp literal , timestamp literal in jpa is in the format `{ts '2009-11-05 12-45-52.325'}` ... just to check , try removing the timestamp from the query then put it again and provide the literals manually ... if it works, you then need to find a way to parse the passed long to the corresponding literal

Answer (score 0):

The problem with it was the field portList.get(0).rack being "null". Appartently this made the whole query not work.